# Create a .xml file which conatins a variable

Tags: xml, macos, unix

I hope someone will be able to assist me on my issue.
I am trying to create a .xml file from a Unix bash script.
My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
getTheDate=$( date | awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}' )

cat > /Users/Admin/Desktop/changeFile.xml << 'EOF'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<changeData>
<Applied>"$getTheDate"</Applied>
<Info>The data was changed successfully</Info>
</changeData>
EOF
```

But when I run the script the result is not what I expected.
This is how the .xml file look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<changeData>
<Applied>"$getTheDate"</Applied>
<Info>The data was changed successfully</Info>
</changeData>
```

Instead of being something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<changeData>
<Applied>Thu 9 Feb 2023 09:45:12</Applied>
<Info>The data was changed successfully</Info>
</changeData>
```

Would anyone be able to help me on this please?

Comment: Do you know what the single quotes in the heredoc name (`'EOF'`) do?

Comment: I got your code to work by removing the quotes around EOF, ref @Shawn's comment.

Comment: That's exactly it!! To answer to Shawn's comment, I have no idea what the single quote or double quote do, yet after removing it, my code worked as I wanted!
Thank you both for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put your delimiter in quotes (i.e. `'EOF'` instead of just `EOF`), you disabled variable expansion. See https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I followed your instruction and now the code works exactly as I wanted to!